# Logic statements. Question from GRE math subject test

Tags: logic

Suppose $A, B,$ and $C$ are statements such that $C$ is true if exactly one of $ A$ and $B$ is true. If $C$ is false which of the following statements must be true?

A) if $A$ is true, then $B$ is false.

B) if $A$ is false, then $B$ is false.

C) if $A$ is false, then $B$ is true.

D) both $A$ and $B$ are true.

E) both $A$ and $B$ are false.

I have two questions.  First question:

$C$ is true if **EXACTLY** one of $A,B$ then the last two choices are right?

second question what is the difference between C) and D) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If C is false then either both A and B are true or false. You don't know which it is for certain, so options D and E are out.

However, if A is true then B must be true as well, otherwise C would be true. If A were false then B must be false for the same reason. You can also exchange A and B and the same argument holds.

Comment: So the answer is B). Thank you very much i see the difference now.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Answer is **E**. Because true of **C** create three options:

- **C** true if **A** is true  but **B** false
- **C** true if **A** is  false but **B** true
- **C** true if both **A** and **B** true.

So the answer will be **E** if both **A** and **B** are false then **C** will be false.

Comment: The third is not correct. If both of A and B are true then C is FALSE since to get C  true EXACTLY one of them should be true